# Switching Devices

Tags: mosfet, diodes, bjt, semiconductors

I am currently working on a project looking at research materials on low voltage but high current switching devices. Is there any technologies/research out there that are rated for high Amp low voltage switches. IF so how would i achieve 80,000 amps.

Comment: Low voltage is precisely what voltage?

Comment: what do you mean by `achieve 80,000 amps` ... do you mean `switch 80 kA` or `generate 80 kA`?

Comment: Generate up to 80kA..

Comment: @FaizanFstahShah putting your questions in context, and in context with your comments: you don't seem to have a solid basic electrical engineer education, so there's simply far too many things we'd have to explain to you to even make remotely sense of what we're writing. So, this is far too broad. Vote to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how would i achieve 80,000 amps

[image]

Comment: How do you intend to get this dog to hunt? / diode to switch ?

Comment: It takes some doing but, if you're into big (and I mean big) DC power links between (say) mainland and islands then you have a few joules spare.

Comment: NZ has 3? cable pairs across Cook Strait. between The North and The South Island. Memory says + and - 500 kV DC. Signs warn of navigation hazards due to compass swing. Also a no anchoring zone. That could get exciting.